# Mobile No printing without + sign and scientific notation when writing csv file using apache commons csv library and java

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons

I am using apache commons csv library to write data to csv file. I have a column to print mobileNo which is in String format, but the + sign in the mobile No is not printing in the csv file. See the below sample code.

Sample MobileNo = "+9212314242342";

```java
  String mobileNo =  t.getCustomer().getMobileNo().getDisplayNumber();
        csvPrinter.printRecord(
                t.getCustomer().getName(),
                mobileNo,
                t.getCreatedDate().getDisplayDateTime(),
                t.getDueDate().getDisplayDateTime(),
                t.getUpdatedDate().getDisplayDateTime(),
                t.getNote());
```

But in the csv file it prints as 9212314242342 and if the number is more than 15 characters it displays in scientific form in the csv file. Anyone experience this ? can you please help me on this. Let me know if you need further information.

Comment: Did you look at the raw contents of the csv file, or did you open it in a spreadsheet program?

Comment: @Danny_ds I opened it using a spreadsheet program (LibreOffice) , Seems like it's an happening due to the data type, i appended a tab in front of mobileNo and now the + sign is visible, but it's kind of a hack, do you have any idea ?

Comment: Looks like it's ok inside the csv, but the software does the formatting in another way. Maybe you could adjust the formatting for the cell or column, or suround the contents like this in the csv file: `="+9212314242342"` (this is a bit of an Excel hack - not standard csv - but I think LibreOffice will accept it too).

Comment: @Danny_ds I'll try this and let you know.